# gorm raw query argument

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, raw-query-builder

I am trying to get some records from postgresql database using gorm raw query.

```
includedStates := []string{"new", "old"}
selectStatement := `select u.department, u.position, u.city, u.join_date, v.name as venture,
      ud.first_name_fa, ud.last_name_fa, ud.cellphone from my_schema.users u
      inner join my_schema.ventures v on u.venture_id = v.id
      left join my_schema.details ud on ud.user_id = u.id
      where status in ? AND join_date::date = (NOW() + INTERVAL '?' day)::date;`

var result []models.User

if err := ur.db.
    Raw(selectStatement, includedStates, days).
    Scan(&result).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

But I get following error on `Scan`:

```
expected 3 arguments, got 4
```

I have exactly two variables and I pass the string query plus two arguments to the `Raw` method.

Besides, I got the query from logs and it returns records with no error in the database console.

**EDIT 1:**

The `days` variable is the input of the method with type `int`.

If I remove the quotation around second `?`, gorm assumes it is a variable and I get the following error (I passed number `4` to the method in this case):

```
syntax error at or near "$4" (SQLSTATE 42601)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have fixed it by removing the second `?` and use it inline; not as a variable:

```
selectStatement := `select u.department, u.position, u.city, u.join_date, v.name as venture,
      ud.first_name_fa, ud.last_name_fa, ud.cellphone from my_schema.users u
      inner join my_schema.ventures v on u.venture_id = v.id
      left join my_schema.details ud on ud.user_id = u.id
      where status in ? AND join_date::date = (NOW() + INTERVAL '` + strconv.Itoa(days) + `' day)::date;`
```

I still don't know what is wrong with the first query, since it was a normal integer variable. So, I will keep the question open.

Comment: would you remove single quote around second question mark and see if there is any difference?
also place first question mark inside parentheses

Comment: can you show days var?

Comment: Please  review my edit @MohamadKarimisalim

Comment: You don't need the single qutoes for the interval argument just use ?. If the type is not string convert the argument to char with a sql function and then concat it with the 'days'

Comment: Please review the Edit 1 section @Eldar